Microsoft Graph api Error: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'dataSubjectRequest'."

We try to run this api in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.
"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/subjectRightsRequests/7af04277-68bf-49f4-befe-72f0fb33d0e1"
We pass all body & token which needed but
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://aedservice-apc02.cloudapp.net/compliance/privacyManagement/dataSubjectRequest('7af04277-68bf-49f4-befe-72f0fb33d0e1')'.\",\"messageDetail\":\"No type was found that matches the controller named 'dataSubjectRequest'.\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-06-24T10:43:20",
            "request-id": "0e8191a0-bc38-483a-869f-9cc726fa6b42",
            "client-request-id": "c11b4170-67ba-a9a8-8163-073b6f5a6381"
        }
    }
}

Fix the Error in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Hi, As the error says its unable to understand or get the ID. Can you try with the sample data that is given in this document and see if it works.
